# Using pefile returns unicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have imported pefile and using it to fetch entries from the StringTable attribute.

I get the below error:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
>       Traceback (most recent call last): File "peinfo.py", line 74, in getPeInfo     ans.append("Product Name      : {}".format(convert_to_printable(st_entry.entries.get('ProductName', 'none'))))
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

A gist of my changes are :

```
def getPeInfo(filename):
    ans = []
    try:
        pe = pefile.PE(filename, fast_load=True)
    except:
        return "PE header not found."

    pe.parse_data_directories( directories=[ 
        pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY['IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT'],
        pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY['IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE'],
         ])
    ans.append("\n [[ File Info]]")
    if hasattr(pe, 'FileInfo'):
        if type(pe.FileInfo) == type([]):
            entry = pe.FileInfo[0]
            if hasattr(entry, 'StringTable'):
                st_entry = entry.StringTable[0]
                ans.append("Product Name : {}".format(convert_to_printable(st_entry.entries.get('ProductName', 'none'))))
```

Comment: That's a pretty large expression, and there are multiple places it could have gone wrong. Can you break it up into a series of separate lines that each do one step, and see which one of those steps raises the exception?

Comment: Anyway, when you're not explicitly calling `decode` anywhere, and not doing something silly like calling `encode` on something that's already a `str`, that error usually means you're trying to use a `str` and a `unicode` together in the same expression—whether that's `x.format(y)`, `x+y`, etc. When you do that, Python automatically calls `decode()` on the `str`, which uses your default encoding, which is usually `ascii`, hence the error. But without a [mcve] it's very hard to track it down any farther.